# Loop file names in label vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, loops, directory

Using vb.net, how can I loop through all file names in a given directory and then display them in a label?

```
Dim PATH_DIR_1 As String
Dim INTERVAL_DIR_1 As String

PATH_DIR_1 = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SOFTWARE\Sidewinder", "DIR_1", "")

INTERVAL_DIR_1 = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SOFTWARE\Sidewinder", "INT_DIR_1", "")

For Each foundFile As String In (PATH_DIR_1)
    Label1.Text = (foundFile)
Next
```

Comment: You say you want to loop through file names, but your code shows a registry path. Which do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of filenames of a directory with:

```
Dim sFiles() as String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sDirectoryPath)
```

And then add it in a `Label` in the way you want:

```
For Each s As String in sFiles
    Label1.Text &= s & "/"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.IO` has a lot of classes for working with the windows file system, here's an example for what you want to do:

```
Imports System.IO

......

Sub DisplayFileList(ByRef theLabel As Label, ByVal thePath As String)

    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(thePath)

    For Each fi As FileInfo In di.GetFiles()

        theLabel.Text &= fi.FullName 'or just fi.Name, FullName is the complete path

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
Imports System.IO
...
For Each filePathAsString In Directory.EnumerateFiles("DirPath")
   Label1.Text = filePathAsString
Next
```